# WPF adding version in text

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

why this is not working?

XAML:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Ver}"/>
```

CODE:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public Version Ver=> Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version;
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

why is this not working?
do i need another dll?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make the binding work you have to set `DataContext` property of the `TextBlock` element itself or the parent element, e.g. the `MainWindow`:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public Version Ver=> Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version;
    public MainWindow()
    {
        DataContext = this;
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Note that this is a minimal working example. It's better to follow MVVM pattern and create a separate `INotifyPropertyChanged` implementation class with `Ver` property and set the `DataContext` to the implementation instance instead of the window itself.